# MySQLi update and die(); and exit(); not working

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, exit, die

I'm trying to replace my MySQL with MySQLi, and i get results - that's ok but when it comes to update MySQL my code fails ( I updated only the MySQL part)

**inc_mysql_connect.php**

```
$db = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $dbase) or die ();
```

**inc_global_functions.php**

```
if($_POST['costAlertTrue'] != "") {

// CHECKS AND IF ERROR - REDIRECT BACK
if(..) {$_SESSION['status'] ="E1"; header("Location: ./?page=cAlert"); exit();}
if(..) ...

// SQL
$sql = "UPDATE ".$dbprfx."_users SET costAlertVar = ? WHERE connection = ?";
$eintrag = $db->prepare($sql);
if ($eintrag->error()) { print($eintrag->error()); }
$eintrag->bind_param('ss',$costAlertVar,$userConnection);
$eintrag->execute();
$eintrag->close();

// REDIRECT 
$_SESSION['status'] ="on"; header("Location: ./?page=cAlert");

} // End
```

Can Anyone find an Error in this piece of code?

**Notice**

```
if($_POST['costAlertTrue'] != "") {
die('XX'); exit('XX');
}
```

It seems that die(); exit(); or any other errors are not working in the if clause

Comment: I wonder how long will it take for local professionals to solve this incredible problem.

Comment: Use isset for that POST

Comment: $costAlertVar,$userConnection probably one or both are not set.

Comment: I tried with if(isset($_POST['costAlertTrue'])) {.. and still nothing but i can get errors with Header Location and $var

Answer (score 0):

Line `$eintrag->error(); {die('Not Working');}` will die every time, even if everything was good, because PHP will see statement `$eintrag->error()` and code block `{die('Not Working');}`.

You should use is like this:

```
if (!$eintrag->error()) { die('Not Working'); }
```

Comment: thx, i updated the code but that is not the problem. still not working

Answer (score 0):

Doesnt this mean if no error die

```
if (!$eintrag->error()) { die('Not Working'); }
```

Remove the !

Comment: ok i removed that but the thing is: i get no errors in this whole if statement. i tried with die(); exit(); etc. All the checks before sql are working properly.

Comment: @user2987790 Echo the $sql.

Comment: echo $sql; die(); exit(); not working so i did: header("Location: $sql"); and it gives me: UPDATE cms_users SET costAlertVar = ? WHERE connection = ?

Answer (score 0):

Thx for all your help, i tried all your tips but suddenly it worked

```
$sql = "UPDATE ".$dbprfx."_users SET costAlertVar = ? WHERE connection = ?";
$eintrag = $db->prepare( $sql );
$eintrag->bind_param('ss',$costAlertVar,$userConnection);
$eintrag->execute();
$eintrag->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

what happens if you replace your main if statement with the following? I've made it fairly simple so as long as you are passing the $db variable properly, this should give you back SOME kind of result.

```
if($_POST['costAlertTrue'] != "") {
    // CHECKS AND IF ERROR - REDIRECT BACK
    if(..) {$_SESSION['status'] ="E1"; header("Location: ./?page=cAlert"); exit();}
    if(..) ...

    // SQL
    $sql = "UPDATE ".$dbprfx."_users SET costAlertVar = ? WHERE connection = ?";


    //$eintrag = $db->prepare($sql);
    //if ($eintrag->error()) { print($eintrag->error()); }
    if($db->connect_errno > 0){
            die("Error connecting to db.");
    }

    //$eintrag->bind_param('ss',$costAlertVar,$userConnection);
    //$eintrag->execute();
    if(!$result = query($sql)){
            die("Error running query");
    }
    //$eintrag->close();
    $db->close();

    // REDIRECT 
    $_SESSION['status'] ="on"; header("Location: ./?page=cAlert");

} // End
```

Also I noticed that you are using an or die statement in your mysqlic_connect statement that contains no error text. If in fact you can't connect there, your script is dying at the start with no output. This would also be a cause of the problem.